# cannot open a Talend Open Studio project

Tags: etl, talend

When I start TOS, I import existing project (from SVN) with TOS 3.1.4.r29781 (talend.project file sepcify this product version)

Here is the stack trace in the "Repository" window :

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.talend.repository.model.AbstractEMFRepositoryFactory.getRecycleBinItems(Unknown
>   Source)

[image: Talend Open Studio NullPointerException]

And here is the stack trace in the "Job" window :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorViewPart
>   cannot be cast to org.talend.repository.ui.views.RepositoryView   at
>   org.talend.repository.RepositoryService.getRepositoryTreeView(Unknown
>   Source)

[image: Talend Open Studio ClassCastException]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=47283

1. import existing project
2. get the errors/Exception
3. export archive
4. create new project
5. in Repositorywindow > right click in empty zone > import > select archive > select all > Finish